# mysql left join not show null value

Tags: mysql

There are two tables as below:

The first one called test1 and has 3 rows:

```
materialid | materialname
a3e110045d154520a8abd858483f50c5 | apple 
ac90fd832b124abeb1a330071d5e4417  | balanna 
ac90fd832b124abeb1a3300711321231  | pear
```

The second one called test2 and has 5 rows:

```
order | materialid
o001   | a3e110045d154520a8abd858483f50c5
o001   | ac90fd832b124abeb1a330071d5e4417
o002   | a3e110045d154520a8abd858483f50c5
o002   | ac90fd832b124abeb1a330071d5e4417
o002   | ac90fd832b124abeb1a3300711321231
```

sql like this :

```
SELECT * from test1 a left join test2 b on a.materialid=b.materialid
```

result:

```
a3e110045d154520a8abd858483f50c5    apple   o002    a3e110045d154520a8abd858483f50c5
a3e110045d154520a8abd858483f50c5    apple   o001    a3e110045d154520a8abd858483f50c5
ac90fd832b124abeb1a3300711321231    pear    o002    ac90fd832b124abeb1a3300711321231
ac90fd832b124abeb1a330071d5e4417    balanna o002    ac90fd832b124abeb1a330071d5e4417
ac90fd832b124abeb1a330071d5e4417    balanna o001    ac90fd832b124abeb1a330071d5e4417
```

there is no null in test2,

i want get the below result,how to do it?

```
a3e110045d154520a8abd858483f50c5    apple   o002    a3e110045d154520a8abd858483f50c5
a3e110045d154520a8abd858483f50c5    apple   o001    a3e110045d154520a8abd858483f50c5
ac90fd832b124abeb1a3300711321231        pear    null   null 
ac90fd832b124abeb1a3300711321231    pear    o002    ac90fd832b124abeb1a3300711321231
ac90fd832b124abeb1a330071d5e4417    balanna o002    ac90fd832b124abeb1a330071d5e4417
ac90fd832b124abeb1a330071d5e4417    balanna o001    ac90fd832b124abeb1a330071d5e4417
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT *           -- replace with needed columns list
-- generate complete (order, materialid) values pairs
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT materialid FROM test2 ) materialids
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT order FROM test2 ) orders
-- then join existing data
LEFT JOIN test2 USING (order, materialid)
LEFT JOIN test1 USING (materialid)
-- WHERE if needed
```

Comment: thanks, but the result not null

Comment: @Mike You have not read "replace with needed columns list"? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=07f887284ae2cda1eecd687c5214fb69